# PCRE Regex help needed

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I am having trouble writing a perl compatible regex to match a few different things when there is a gap between each condition.  It makes more sense when I explain what I want it to find

**Conditions**

1. /world/
2. a single letter
3. a dash OR underscore
4. a single letter
5. a single period
6. three or four letters

The problem I have is I don't know how to write the expression such that there can be a gap between condition #1 and #2.  Conditions #2 - #4 can repeat, but not always.

I've been using multiple online regex testers but I cannot get a match and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I think regex is looking for `/world/x_x`  or `/world/y-y` instead of "looking ahead" to match on the "letter dash letter" or "letter underscore letter" pattern.

**Current regex**

```
/world/([a-z](-|_)[a-z]){1,}\.[a-z]{3,4}$
```

**Desired Matches** (not currently matching)

```
hxxp://armassimchilzeispreu.blackjackipad.com/world/activate_available.jar

hxxp://chubfaceddamsel0.affittobarcheavela.it/world/eternal_threat-clearing.html

hxxp://offdestroyengarabitar.freebookofraslot.com/world/bonus-middle-marathon.pdf
```

Comment: Your desired matches don't seem to match the conditions you're using. You say you want strings starting with `/world/[a single letter][- or _][another single letter]`, but then you say you want it to match `/world/activate_available.jar`. "activate" and "available" are both much longer than one character.

Comment: Also, `eternal_threat-clearing.html`and `bonus-middle-marathon.pdf` have more than one "hyphen-or-underscore".

Comment: @user1618143 - I say x-x or y_y because I just want to ensure that pattern is there, I don't care how long or what word is in the URL.  I know the URLs have full words but I don't care about what word is there. Do I have to match on word-word or word_word in their entirety?

Comment: @Borodin - yes, that's why I am trying to write the regex as one or more {1,} is my unerstanding of how that works.

Comment: Ah I see. Take a look at my answer. Is that what you want? Also, `{1,}` is traditionally written as `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  print "OK $_\n" if m</world/[a-z]+(?:[_-][a-z]+)+\.[a-z]{3,4}$>;
}

__DATA__
hxxp://armassimchilzeispreu.blackjackipad.com/world/activate_available.jar
hxxp://chubfaceddamsel0.affittobarcheavela.it/world/eternal_threat-clearing.html
hxxp://offdestroyengarabitar.freebookofraslot.com/world/bonus-middle-marathon.pdf
```

or perhaps just

```
m</world/[a-z-_]+\.[a-z]{3,4}$>
```

Comment: I think this is it!  If you don't mind, would you explain what you did?  I am not that familiar with the ?: (non-capturing subpattern according to documentation).  I would like to study this so I can better understand it.  You have no idea how elated I am at having this signature solved, but I do want to ensure I understand it :D

Comment: Just noticed your second expression. That one works as well.  I'm trying to dissect it.

Comment: The [a-z-_]+ - match on any letters,dash, or underscore one or more times. One thing, I may be wrong but this will match on a string even if it doesn't have a - or _ . Is there any way to make it having a -|_ mandatory to be in the string?